# Could not autowire. No beans of ... type found. External jar decompiled .class file

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have an issue with starting my SpringBootApplication. I'm new to Spring and already looked at existing questions on StackOverflow, but they didn't help me.

I have an `EventSourcingConfig` where `EventSourcingServiceFactory` declared as `@Autowired`.

```
package com.cinephilia.review.config

import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.CommentAggregate
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.CommentAggregateState
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.RatingAggregate
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.RatingAggregateState
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory
import java.util.*

@Configuration
class EventSourcingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var eventSourcingServiceFactory: EventSourcingServiceFactory

    @Bean
    open fun commentService() = eventSourcingServiceFactory.create<UUID, CommentAggregate, CommentAggregateState>()

    @Bean
    open fun ratingService() = eventSourcingServiceFactory.create<UUID, RatingAggregate, RatingAggregateState>()
}
```

This is external dependency for my application and it's declared in my `build.gradle.kts`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("ru.quipy:tiny-event-sourcing-spring-boot-starter:2.3.0")
    ...
}
```

I can *Ctrl-click* to `EventSourcingServiceFactory` and go to implementation `EventSourcingServiceFactory`.

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package ru.quipy.core

public final class EventSourcingServiceFactory public constructor(aggregateRegistry: ru.quipy.core.AggregateRegistry, eventMapper: ru.quipy.mapper.EventMapper, eventStore: ru.quipy.database.EventStore, eventSourcingProperties: ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties) {
    public final val aggregateRegistry: ru.quipy.core.AggregateRegistry /* compiled code */

    public final val eventMapper: ru.quipy.mapper.EventMapper /* compiled code */

    public final val eventSourcingProperties: ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties /* compiled code */

    public final val eventStore: ru.quipy.database.EventStore /* compiled code */

    public final inline fun <ID : kotlin.Any, reified A : ru.quipy.domain.Aggregate, S : ru.quipy.domain.AggregateState<ID, A>> create(): ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingService<ID, A, S> { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

So when I attempt to start my app with `gradle bootRun` it's failing to start with error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field eventSourcingServiceFactory in com.cinephilia.review.config.EventSourcingConfig required a bean of type 'ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory' in your configuration.
```

Thus how can I solve this problem? Setting the `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoconfiguration` didn't help me. I consider that problem is that `EventSourcingServiceFactory` isn't anotated. But how can I do this, when it is external dependency for my application and all I have it's jar file.

I tried to set up `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` for my SpringBootApplication

Comment: You also have to define an `EventSourcingServiceFactory` as a Spring bean if you want to be able to autowire it into your `EventSourcingConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method annotated with @Bean that return an instace of type `EventSourcingServiceFactory`

Or create another class that extends the `EventSourcingServiceFactory` class and you need to anotate it by `@Bean` so that spring will find it in the context when autowiring

Example :

```
@Bean
public Class EventSourcingServiceFactory2 extends EventSourcingServiceFactory {
}
```